# Visual Studio Code ES6 Syntax Highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, riot.js

Does anyone know how to trigger syntax highlighting for `<script type=“es6”></script>` inside `.html` files? The JavaScript code inside these tags are not highlighted (see screenshot bellow), as I expected, by Visual Studio Code...

I’m on:

- Visual Studio Code 1.27.2
- macOS Mojave 10.14

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This question belongs on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think `"es6"` is a valid `type` value? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type

Comment: @Phil, I’m pre-compiling Riot (https://riot.js.org) tags that use Ecmascript6 syntax, and for that to work with Babeljs, I need to enabled it using `type="es6”`.